# Pyodbc Store html unicode string in Sql Server

Tags: python

I want to store html string in `sql server database` using `pyodbc driver`. I have used `nvarchar(max)`as the data type for storing in the database but it is throwing the following error

Error:

> ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Warning: Partial insert/update. The insert/update of a text or image column(s) did not succeed. (0) (SQLPutData); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified. (7125)')

Comment: Can it be an ODBC driver issue? The driver you are using may not support writing large text? See here https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=277

Answer (score 2):

The link that Anthony Kong supplied includes something that may resolve the issue; it did for me in a very similar situation.

> switch to DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} instead of DRIVER={SQL Server} in the connection string

This would be for Sql Server 2008 (you didn't specify the Edition); for Sql Server 2012 it would be Native Client 11.0.

Comment: Or you can use 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'  driver